# C++ linker troubles with DirectX in Windows SDK

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, directx

I'm writing a game for Windows 7 and 8. I've been using VS2012. So basically I'm trying to get my head around the Windows SDK. d3dX10math has been replaced, I've come to terms with that, and I've included DirectXMath.h where necessary.

The problem comes, as it so often does, with the linker. It's not linking to the necessary library. They are right there in external dependencies (I'm assuming that the old d3dx10math.lib has been replaced by these .inl files?). I can't find an equivalent .lib file so that's what I'm assuming.

It just doesn't want to actually link to them. I've searched high and low online and nobody seems to have asked this question. I feel like I've missed something?

```
#ifndef _CDEVICE_H_
#define _CDEVICE_H_

//#include <vector>

#pragma once
//#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")

#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>

using namespace DirectX;

static class cDevice
{
public:
    cDevice();
    cDevice(const cDevice&);
    ~cDevice();
private:
    static ID3D11Device* device;
    static XMFLOAT2 float2;
} device;

#endif
```

and then I get this linker error

```
1>cDevice.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct DirectX::XMFLOAT2 cDevice::float2" (?float2@cDevice@@0UXMFLOAT2@DirectX@@A)
```

Comment: Is the class declaration you posted your own code? If yes, you are probably lacking the definition of the `float2` static member. You should have something like `XMFLOAT2 cDevice::float2;` somewhere in your cpp files.

Comment: Seems I've had a total brain fart with regards to trying to find a solution to having a single instance of a class that handles the device and device context with easy access. Static isn't the way to go!

Comment: static is a storage class specifier. is it incorrect to use with class definition. may be you want to declare device in another line after class definition is completed.

Answer (score 1):

`static XMFLOAT2 float2;` in your header as a class member requires you have a .cpp file (say CDevice.cpp) in your project that has `XMFLOAT2 Device::float2( 0, 0 );`--or whatever initial value you expect to have--in it to actually declare the variable. That makes `CDevice::float2` a static member variable of the class. You have declared your CDevice to have a `static ID3D11Device* device;`, which again would require a .cpp file with `ID3D11Device* CDevice::device = nullptr;` in it to link.

Also, don't put using namespace statements in your headers. They are great in .cpp files, but in headers you should stick with full names like: `DirectX::XMFLOAT2`.

A .h like this:

```
static class cDevice
{
public:
    cDevice();
    cDevice(const cDevice&);
    ~cDevice();
private:
    static ID3D11Device* device;
    static DirectX::XMFLOAT2 float2;
} device;
```

would require a .cpp file like this:

```
#include "CDevice.h" using namespace DirectX;
using namespace DirectX;

ID3D11Device* CDevice::device = nullptr;
XMFLOAT2 CDevice::float2(0, 0);
```

And if you ever included that .h in more than one .cpp file you'd find that every one has it's own unrelated CDevice copy in it.

I don't know why you'd want to do any of that as that makes little sense as a design (you should have non-static variables in your class `CDevice`, or you should be using a `namespace CDevice` instead since you aren't actually using object encapsulation, or maybe make a singleton). You should probably read a primer on C++ to get the basics of these as it has nothing at all to do with DirectX in particular, and you appear very confused about the use of the (admittedly heavily overloaded) keyword `static`.

I would strongly suggest you take a look at using the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) wrapper for DirectXMath in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), and really the rest of the *DirectX Tool Kit* too.

I'd also suggesting moving to [VS 2013 Community Edition](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) rather than VS 2012 (Express for Windows Desktop?), and using the [Direct3D Win32 Game](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) template as you want to support Windows 7.

Comment: It's 2012 Premium. The MSDN subscription I used to get it had VS 2013 included, but because of the continued subscription model I wasn't sure if my usage of VS2013 would "expire".

Comment: Look at the license terms for VS 2013 Community Edition. It's basically VS 2013 Pro for individuals, indies, students, and hobbyists.

Comment: well my MSDN subscription was with an old job I had, I'm fairly certain it was supposed to expire at the end of October yet I still have full access to Azure, I can still access VS2013 Premium... strange stuff is going on.